# Change today of UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, uidatepicker, today-extension

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the blue today of a UIDatePicker ? Since iOS 4.0, the apps can stay opened for many days and it's a little weird to have a today that  is not today :)

Maybe I can only do this with the regular picker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simply a bug! Please file it at Apple to get this fixed.